# Length of tendon in circle

Tags: geometry, circles

What is the length of chord that pass on two specific point.

For example I have circle ( r=1) 
point1 :(x1,y1)
point2(x2,y2);
length of chord?

Comment: what about the distance formula? is tendon another word for a chord?

Comment: yes , I mean chord. I don't know what is formula. I wanna ask you

Comment: distance between $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ is $\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2}$

Comment: are the points on the circle? or do we need to find where the line cuts the circle first?

Comment: no they aren't on Perimeter . @abel

Comment: You say, "$r = 1$"  Are you assuming the circle is centered at the origin?

Comment: yes    @jameselmore

Comment: see the answer i posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is how you will do. any point on the line connecting $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ can be written in the form $$x = tx_2 + (1-t)x_1, y = ty_2 + (1-t)y_1$$ for the point $(x,y)$ to be on the unit circle, $t$ needs to satisfy 
$$  \left(tx_2 + (1-t)x_1 \right)^2+ \left( ty_2 + (1-t)y_1\right)^2 = 1$$

follow these steps:

(a) solve the quadratic equation for $t$

(b) find the two roots $t_1, t_2$

(c) length of the chord is $|t_1 - t_2|\sqrt{(x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2}$